# Persist Android Notifications Event If App is Terminated?

Tags: android, notifications, persist

In my app, when a user executes and event, I add a notification to the notification's bar.  Tapping that notification works both if the app is in the foreground or if it is backgrounded.

I would like the notification to persist even if the app is terminated (due to memory, etc.).  And have the notification tap relaunch the app.

Is that, at all, possible?

I've searched all over and can't find an answer.

I have set my notification flags to Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR so the user can't clear it, but upon app termination, the notification gets removed.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the notification to be managed by a service. Services can be configured to restart automatically on termination.